# Best Way to Do a Data List View Refresh in JSF?

Tags: jsf, datatable, refresh, prerenderview

What is the best way to assure that a list of data entries is refreshed in a JSF XHTHML view?

After reading documentation, I implemented an event as follows:

```
<f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{myDataCtlr.onloadListView}"/>
```

However, it appears that the onloadListView() does not always get invoked when the page is refreshed or transitioned into.  The data table in the view needs to get refreshed with the latest data whenever the view is re-entered.  Is there any way to do this without invoking an active method that reloads data using the following type of code:

```
<h:dataTable value="#{myDataCtlr.reloadItems()}" >
```

Comment: If the page is really 'refreshed', the `onloadListView` is with 100% certainty called. Check the browser console if there really is a new request going to the server (meaning the page is not retrieved from the local cache). And why is it a problem to call `reloadItems()`? Since  it **needs** to be called to actually refresh the data in the datatable.

Comment: @Kukeltje Thanks for your response about the certainty of the listener invocation.  I will have to troubleshoot the problem from that starting point.  With regard to the reloadItems() method call, it was my understanding that the binding for the dataTable value is supposed to be an actual data variable with getter / setter and not a functional method like reloadItems().  Is this not correct?  I did bring it up because I know it will definitely get called from the dataTable value assignment, but was not sure if the value should be binded to an actual variable and not a dynamic method.

Comment: It usually is a getter but a full method works too, provided the method returns the right type AND you do not do any real work in it (or do it lazyly)